# how can I protect against capture during encryption/salt for php ajax login

Tags: php, ajax, encryption, authentication, salt

If a password is encrypted before ajax, what is to stop a hacker from capturing the encrypted password and using it to log in?

Should a unique salt be sent from the backend beforehand? 
 Wouldn't a hacker be able to capture that too?

**background to my question:**
I worked through this tutorial
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL
**summary of tutorial**
browser side encrypts password before sending it to backend where it is stored in db

From that link, the first comment stuck in my mind
"what's to prevent a hacker from capturing the hashed password and logging in?"

Comment: Web applications without HTTPS are totally insecure against active attackers no matter how much javascript crypto your throw at it. The best you can do is defending against passive attackers, with SRP or similar schemes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing. Hashing the password on the client is a terrible idea.

Communication between the browser and server should be properly encrypted using SSL (via HTTPS).

Hashing on the client side has two effects:

- It provides a false sense of security to the site owner by suggesting that it can substitute for SSL
- It adds a dependency on JavaScript

Comment: I'm not using https for this unless it becomes profitable. Looking for best non-https solutions I can find

Comment: Using HTTPS will be cheaper then doing the work needed to create something not-as-good as HTTPS.

Comment: I've contacted my hosting and little did I know they offer and SSL really cheaply. Once its implemented and I'm using https what other techniques should I be using or am I now safe?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/ is a good reference. Primary attacks most people need to worry about that SSL won't defend from as SQL Injection, XSS and CSRF.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit silly, really.  As Quentin stated, all you've done at this point is change what the password **is**, you havent made it any more secure.  Now, instead of the password being 'private string', it is sha1('private string').  Which happens to be '5ee913d43470d39020f15ac10ff9cf7a8761b55a' if you hex-encode it.

All you've done is trade one password for another.

To exchange passwords securely your best option is to use HTTPS.  Hands down.  If for some reason you can't get HTTPS working or you don't want to pay for the certificate then you'll have to get creative.

Your hardest problem to overcome is the at the initial stage where the user sets their password.  Without using public-key cryptography, your best option is to pass a randomly-generated symmetric key in the form, and use that key to encrypt the password at the client end, and decrypt it at the server end.  It can be broken if someone happens to be watching the exchange.  But this is a problem that can't be solved without public key crypto.

Once the password is set logins can be done very securely.  When the server renders the login form for the client, it can generate a nonce as part of the form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='nonce' value='b45354f5b437c82beeed71d4d56ef3a47d0df2d3'/>
Username: <input type='text' name='username'/><br/>
Password: <input type='password' name='password'/>
```

Using a Javascript and a crypto library such as [crypt-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/), the client creates a hashed message.  The message should include a timestamp, the username, and the nonce.  Then create an HMAC.

```
var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
var message = '' + ts + ':' + username + ':' + nonce;
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(message, password);
```

Long story short, the hash is the message hashed together with the password.

Now send the message and the hash to the server.  The server has to reverse the process:

- parse the message into the nonce, date, and username
- make sure the nonce was the same one that was given to the client
- make sure the date is recent (within the last 5 minutes, say)
- retrieve the user's password
- perform the HMAC computation, and make sure the outcome equals the hash provided by the client.

Comment: the code u posted relates to secure login after the password is established, correct?

Comment: I'm not using https for this unless it becomes profitable. Looking for best non-https solutions I can find. What do you think about this - if I email the salt to the user who is signing up. That way they establish the password at the time of email verification

Comment: Yes, the code is for loggin in AFTER the password has been set.  As for using email to pass crypto component around: you get a little extra security from the extra indirection, but only because it makes sniffing more inconvenient.  Any kind of secure key exchange on an unsecure network requires public-key cryptography.  That means using either HTTPS or finding a Javascript pkcs library and learning to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you posted does not only hash on the client side... they hash on the server side as well.

Basically on that registration page, something JavaScript will hash the user's password and send it to the server.  Presumably, this is to stop someone from getting the password in transit.  Once the hashed password is sent to the server side, it is salted and hashed again.

This method is safe... but I'm not sure I see the merits of hashing on the client if you are using HTTPS, which you should be.

Comment: It isn't safe, at best it is pointless. The hashed password is the token that has to be sent to the server to login as the user. Effectively, the hashed password is the real password. If it is sniffed, then the attacker can log in as the user.

Comment: @Quentin, Yes, I understand what you are saying.  Please re-read the tutorial he linked to.  It's a bit unconventional, but it is safe.  It's effectively no different than just doing hashing on the server side, from a security standpoint.

Comment: slashingweapon's solution is a good one, for that part of the system

Comment: @Brad thanks for checking out the tutorial I linked to and for answering on my thread. I have many questions because you are going against the grain here and saying it is safe (and I respect that). I'm not trying to poke holes in what you're saying but I do want to learn. The biggest question on my mind is this - if the encrypted password can be sniffed and the view-source of the javascript can reveal the sha encryption, then can;t the hacker figure out the password thereby nullifying the additional server side encryption?

Comment: @PrimeLens, Yes. Let me back up a bit.  Your tutorial does server-side hashing in the traditional way.  The client sends a "password", the server salts it, and then stores the hash and the salt in the database.  From that standpoint, it is secure.  On top of this, your tutorial also hashes the password client-side, prior to sending it to the server.  We all agree that this is effectively pointless.  The system is secure (from a hashing point of view) in that it does it server-side.  On top of this, there is the pointless client-side hashing.

Comment: @PrimeLens, The client-side hashing is there, likely because the author of the tutorial thought he was hiding the password from going over the wire.  This doesn't really add any protection because at that point, the hash is effectively the password, and that is all that is needed to login to your server.  A malicious user can simply bypass the client-side hashing and use that client-side hash directly.

Comment: @Brad so the logging in part is secure but the establishing of the password is not?

Comment: @PrimeLens, No, the whole thing is fine.  The additional client-side hashing doesn't hurt anything, but it doesn't help anything either.  Now again, this says nothing for transport security.  If you don't use HTTPS, everything can be sniffed.  All I'm saying is that the server-side hashing method is fine.